# Libgdx : Exported desktop jar file link to external path instead jar root

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libgdx, assets

I'm trying to deploy my libgdx app into a jar desktop file. I use Intellij so i builded the desktop module, then executed  ./gradlew desktop:dist to produce the jar and everything gone well ! I use an Asset manager to load my assets. Now when i execute the jar, the asset manager try to get the assets in the directory of the jar and not directly in the jar file.

My asset manager :

```
package com.com8.game.Utils;

import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetDescriptor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.SkinLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;


public class Assets {

public AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

public static final AssetDescriptor<Texture> logo =
        new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("logo.png", Texture.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<Texture> tableBack =
        new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("back.png", Texture.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<Texture> frontBackground =
        new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("frontBackground.png", Texture.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<Texture> backBackground =
        new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("backBackground.png", Texture.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> uiAtlas =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("UI/uiskin.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<Skin> uiSkin =
        new AssetDescriptor<Skin>("UI/uiskin.json", Skin.class,
                new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("UI/uiskin.atlas"));

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> gameAtlas =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/gameImages.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> flamesAnimation =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/flamesAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> hitAnimation =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/hitAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> shipExplosionAnimation =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/shipExplosionAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);

public static final AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> dustAnimation =
        new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/dustAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);


public void load()
{
    manager.load(logo);
    manager.load(tableBack);
    manager.load(frontBackground);
    manager.load(backBackground);
    manager.load(uiAtlas);
    manager.load(uiSkin);
    manager.load(gameAtlas);
    manager.load(flamesAnimation);
    manager.load(hitAnimation);
    manager.load(shipExplosionAnimation);
    manager.load(dustAnimation);
}

public void dispose() {
    manager.dispose();
}
}
```

My build.gradle of the desktopLauncher : 
    apply plugin: "java"

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.com8.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/core/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project 
generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me ? :) Thanks

EDIT : 
I just added a "/" in front of each path name and it seems to be better ! 
[now i have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyYAd.png), the file logo.png is in the root of the jar file.

And here is how i use Assets class :

```
// Assets
private AssetManager manager;
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;

// UI
private TextField userIDRegistered;
private TextField userPwd;
private TextField userIDGuest;
private Label authentificationResponse;
private Label socketConnectedMessage;

// Socket
private Socket socket;

public ConnexionScreen(Com8 game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.socket = game.getSocket();
    this.manager = game.assets.manager;

    skin = game.skin;

    stage = game.stage;
    stage.clear();

    configSocketEvents();
}

@Override
public void show() {
    //Create Table
    Table mainTable = new Table();

    //Set table position properties
    mainTable.align(Align.center|Align.center);
    mainTable.setFillParent(true);

    //Create image
    Texture logoTexture = manager.get("/logo.png", Texture.class);
    Image logoImage = new Image(logoTexture);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");
```

to

```
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
```

in `build.gradle` file of desktop module

then run `./gradlew desktop:dist`

Hopefully, all of your resources are in assets folder of `android module`.

**EDIT**

I tested, It's working fine for me, find what you're doing wrong.

Code inside `create()` method

```
AssetDescriptor<Texture> assetDescriptor=new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("brick.png",Texture.class);

AssetManager assetManager=new AssetManager();
assetManager.load(assetDescriptor);   // load by assetDescriptor
assetManager.load("badlogic.jpg", Texture.class);   // manual loading

assetManager.finishLoading();

texture=assetManager.get("badlogic.jpg",Texture.class);  // fetch data manually 
texture1=assetManager.get(assetDescriptor);              // fetch by descriptor
```

I draw these two texture in `render()` method

Resources are inside core module in `assets` folder.

[image]

then I assign asset directory in `build.gradle` file of desktop module that is also using in `dist` task

`project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../core/assets");`

Run  `./gradlew dist` command on terminal.

I find my `desktop-1.0.jar` inside build folder of desktop module. Copied and keep in some other folder and run by double click, It's working fine.

Both resources(`badlogic.jpg` & `brick.png`) are in my `.jar` at top root.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but i don't have an android module (i deploy only on desktop) and my assets are located in "../core/assets". when i make the jar the assets are correctly copied in the root of the jar file, so he find them. The problem is that when i try access them in my asset manager, the root path his outside the jar file, so if i put all the assets in the same file of the jar its works perfectly but its not very convenient

Comment: okay got it, can you show me the code, how you're using `Assets` class

Comment: Yes thank you ! The problem was my AssetDescriptors ! They were in static! I don t know why but now its work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem, thanks to @Abhishek Aryan !
My Assets Descriptors was static, when dealing with assets Manager it seems that nothing can be static. I change my Assets class like this :

```
public class Assets {

public AssetManager manager;

public AssetDescriptor<Texture> logo;

public AssetDescriptor<Texture> tableBack;
public AssetDescriptor<Texture> frontBackground;

public AssetDescriptor<Texture> backBackground;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> uiAtlas;

public AssetDescriptor<Skin> uiSkin;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> gameAtlas;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> flamesAnimation;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> hitAnimation;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> shipExplosionAnimation;

public AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas> dustAnimation;

public Assets(){
    manager = new AssetManager();
    logo = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("logo.png", Texture.class);
    tableBack = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("back.png", Texture.class);
    frontBackground = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("frontBackground.png", Texture.class);
    backBackground = new AssetDescriptor<Texture>("backBackground.png", Texture.class);
    uiAtlas = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("UI/uiskin.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    uiSkin = new AssetDescriptor<Skin>("UI/uiskin.json", Skin.class,
            new SkinLoader.SkinParameter("UI/uiskin.atlas"));
    gameAtlas = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/gameImages.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    flamesAnimation = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/flamesAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    hitAnimation = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/hitAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    shipExplosionAnimation = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/shipExplosionAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
    dustAnimation = new AssetDescriptor<TextureAtlas>("Atlas/dustAnimation.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
}

public void load()
{
    manager.load(logo);
    manager.load(tableBack);
    manager.load(frontBackground);
    manager.load(backBackground);
    manager.load(uiAtlas);
    manager.load(uiSkin);
    manager.load(gameAtlas);
    manager.load(flamesAnimation);
    manager.load(hitAnimation);
    manager.load(shipExplosionAnimation);
    manager.load(dustAnimation);
}

public void dispose() {
    manager.dispose();
}
}
```

Everything is working well now :)